# How to clear search result?

Tags: android

I have implemented search function using SearchManager and SearchView in the action bar. The same activity that shows the search view performs the search and shows the search result. This is working fine, and I can get the search query from the onNewIntent() without a problem.

When the user clicks the back button to get out of the search mode, I need to redisplay all items. How do I accomplish this? I tried intercepting OnDismiss and OnCancel of the search manager as well as the OnClose of the search view. Nothing ever gets called. Code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    //Try to detect end of search session. None of the listeners getting called.
    searchManager.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {//...}
    });
    searchManager.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {//...}
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

The manifest file entry for the activity is like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, and I found the solution which is quite simple. If you are using the searchWidget (like me) you simply need to do this:

```
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // Put your code here to clear and display the results
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Because actually what are the user is closing is the SearchView, not the SearchManager. I've just test it and it works like a charm!

Hope this works for you.

Regards